# Unable to change Hotmail password, but can log in

Tags: passwords, hotmail

I logged into my hotmail account and went to change the password. However every time I try, it tells me "password invalid" for my existing password (which works). I think this is because it is an old account and the current password does not match their current criteria of "> 8 chars, upper lower case and numbers". I think this is why I cannot proceed on this screen (some regex is stopping me). Other accounts can have their passwords changed just fine.

Any thoughts as to how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to contact microsoft over their [support-website](https://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ln=en).

You may have to show some informations, that you are the owner of that account.